# How to calculate a new value pair BTC/XAU?

Tags: math, pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

If I know, for example,

```
DOGE/EUR=1:1.323
EUR/USD=1:1.12
JPY/Silver=1:0.81
EUR/JPY=1:12
```

How can I calculate any other value pair I might be interested, given the known value pairs?

```
DOGE/USD=?
DOGE/Silver=?
```

Comment: One would think that this would be a beginners trading tutorial, but not at all. So I'm double checking my math. Is it A/B=1:2, B/C=1:1, A/C=1:0.5. So in pine script that would be AC=(AB*BC)/AB ?

Answer (score 0):

Nils.

```
  DOGE/EUR=1:1.323
  EUR/USD=1:1.12 => EUR=USD:1.12
  DOGE/EUR=DOGE/(USD:1.12)=1:1.323 => DOGE/USD=1:(1.12*1.323)
  DOGE/USD=1:1.48176
```

analogically

```
  DOGE/Silver=1:(1.323*12*0.81)=1:12.85956
```

Ок?

Comment: Mathematically, yes. But can you show how it's done in pine script with an actual plottable series float? ( request.security() and plot() functions )

Comment: It would be perfect if you could screenshot the new pair priceline. Even better if the calculated pair is something which is already availiable, so that it could be compared as a proof of the math.

Comment: And even better if you could explain what are the problematics with this approach when trying to find BTC/XAU or USDC as all three of them are represented by market cap, seemingly.

Comment: If you know EUR/BTC and EUR/XAU, what is the BTC/XAU?

Comment: Given that I didn't find anything from a quick google search I feel that it's not so simple and maybe logically invalid in some cases.

Comment: @NilsRiga change your question and show what you did to solve it yourself.